# Do While loop in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that houses commission by program.  I need to be able to retrieve the names of programs that comprise of 80% of the total commission for a particular month.  I am not sure if I am on the right track and need some help.  Here is what I have so far. Not sure how to retrieve the data from #tmp2 to insert into #tmp3.  Or even if this is the right approach.

```
Declare @total decimal (20,2)
Declare @EOMDate datetime

set @EOMDate = '2015-07-31'
set @total = (select sum(isnull(commission,0)) *.80 from factprograms fp 
join dimdealer dd on fp.dimDealerKey = dd.dimDealerKey 
where dd.Location like 'EU%' and fp.EOMDate = @EOMDate)

Create Table #tmp2(
  ID int primary key IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
  DealerGroupID int,
  DealerGroupName varchar (100),
  Premium decimal (20,2),
  PercentTot decimal (10,5))


insert into #tmp2
select 
DealerGroupID,
Dealergroupname, 
sum(isnull(commission,0)),
sum(isnull(commission,0)/@total)
from factprograms fp 
join dimdealer dd on fp.dimDealerKey = dd.dimDealerKey 
where dd.Location like 'EU%' and fp.EOMDate = @EOMDate
group by dd.DealerGroupID,dd.DealerGroupName
order by sum(commission) desc

select * from #tmp2 order by ID asc

Create table #tmp3(
DealerGroupName varchar(100))




drop table #tmp2,#tmp3
```

Comment: @Engineer Dollery- Yes

Comment: Why do you think you need a loop here? Just write a query that gets the data you need.

Comment: It is unclear what information you are looking for.  Are you looking for records in #tmp2 that have a value of sum(isnull(commission,0)/@total) greater than 0.8?  If so it seems like a rather trivial query.  If not, please provide more context around the data schema and what specific data you are looking for.

Comment: You need to rewrite the question with more details and a clearer taget. By getting the programs that comprise 80% of the monthly commissions mean you're looking for a single program that is 80% of the commissions ? Or a specific group of programs ?  And can you also submit the table structure with some example data and the requested result set.  Because the code you posted calculates the 80% value mark for July2015. But then calculates the commission by groups.  What is the relation between Groups and Programs ?

Comment: I need the group of programs that make up 80% of that months commission.  If I loop through until the records in #tmp2 (they are in order of commission descending) have a total of 1 or above (based on summing PercentTot  field), that would give me the groups I need.  But is this the best way to go?

Comment: Now that I think of it, I would not need the PercentTot field.  I could loop through until the sum of premium reaches the value of @total.  However, I am still unsure the best way to approach this. Here is some example data-

Comment: ID DealerGroupID DealerGroupName Premium
1 163 Cal-Team B 3276451.63
2 1 NY-Team D 3224098.49
3 118 NY-Team C 2507910.19
4 77 TX-Team A 2289496.68
5 124 FL-Team B 1222326.58
6 211 Cal-Team E 782473.09
7 94 FL-Team A 694969.52
8 13 NY-Team B 682690.4
9 75 Cal-Team A 507739.55
10 56 TX-Team C 432802.99
11 112 Cal-Team D 430842.8
12 72 FL-Team D 343799.9
13 49 TX-Team D 326063.23
14 192 Cal-Team C 316279.79
15 129 NY-Team A 263003.59
16 65 TX-Team E 255211.69
17 100 FL-Team C 181450.58
18 222 TX-Team B 169999.22

Comment: Cut down the example in order to view better

Comment: ID DealerGroupID DealerGroupName Premium
1 163 Cal-Team B 3276451.63
2 1 NY-Team D 3224098.49
3 118 NY-Team C 2507910.19
4 77 TX-Team A 2289496.68
5 124 FL-Team B 1222326.58
6 211 Cal-Team E 782473.09
7 94 FL-Team A 694969.52
8 13 NY-Team B 682690.4

Comment: Sorry-table not pasting correctly.  Anyways, the grand total of the commission of the second data set is 14680416.58.  80% of that is 11744333.  I would grab the first five records because their total is 12,520,283 (first 4 records total 11,297,956)